# Timing the display of JPanels

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, jpanel

I have an annoying issue with my desktop app that I am just unable to figure out. I have isolated the problem into the following example. What I am trying to do....

I have a jframe and 5 jpanels, each panel has a different picture. When launched, the user will see panel A with a button all inside my jframe. When the button is pressed I would like panel A to dissappear and panel B,C,D and E become visible after one another but each panel to be displayed for different lengths of time...
B visible for 3 secs, B invisible, C visible for 5 seconds, C invisible... and so on.

I have tried javax.Timer, Thread.sleep(3000) and even for statements and none seem to achieve what I want. How would you guys achieve this and what is the method I need to be looking at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you tried with the Swing Timer?

Comment: A Label instead of panels ?

Comment: I actually have each panel with a jlabel that holds an icon. Instead of swapping the icons I would like to swap the panels.

Comment: Any specific reason for that ?

Comment: @joeyrohan It really doesn't matter what component he's using. His problem is making the component visible for a certain amount of time. Telling him to use a different type of component isn't really answering the question, IMHO.

Comment: not realy, its just that is the way it is at the moment, and what I have been working on up until now. If its best to change this, then that is what I will do.

Comment: not realy, its just that is the way it is at the moment, and what I have been working on up until now. If its best to change this, then that is what I will do.

Comment: @KevinWorkman What if I have to show 1000 pictures ? Add same amount of panels ? I hope you get my point.

Comment: @dazbrad Then create some kind of data structure that stores how long each should be shown, and refer to that data structure to set the Timer interval.

Comment: Also check out [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for switching between panels

Comment: @KevinWorkman was talking about something like this.Check out the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a Swing Timer sounds like a reasonable approach. When the user clicks the JButton, show B and start the Timer, which should have an interval of 3 seconds. When the Timer fires, show C and change the Timer's interval to 5 seconds. When it fires again, show C and set the interval for however long you want to show C.

If that isn't working, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried, and we'll go from there.

Comment: So Timers were the right way of doing this. As uploading my code with my phone is difficult as hell, I will look into different tutorials about Timers before uploading code. Ill get back to this thread with the code if my attempts fail. Thanks for the guidance fellas.

Answer (score -1):

Here I have done an example which shows:

- How to use a `Swing` timer
- How to add images on `JLabel` without freezing the program
- Swapping the pics with the help of an timing array

[image: Before]

After timer starts its starts changing   :

[image]

**My SSCCE:**

```
     /**
     *
     * @author rohan
     */

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class TestSwapPics  {


    public TestSwapPics() {
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame f =new JFrame();

        Panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images.jpg")));
        jButton1.setText("Start");

        Panel.add(jLabel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Panel.add(jButton1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.add(Panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });


    }

      private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      startPicsChange();
    }


    private void startPicsChange() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Timer t = createAndStartTimer(timings[count],count);

                while (t.isRunning()) {//wait for timer to be done
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        count++;
                        if (count == timings.length) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");

                        } else {
                            startPicsChange();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    private Timer createAndStartTimer(int delay, final int count) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(count==0)
                 jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/p3.PNG")));
                if(count==1)
                 jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/p6.PNG")));
                System.out.println("yes! reached here");

            }
        });

        Timer t = new Timer(delay, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("here 2!!");
            }

        });
        t.setRepeats(false);
        t.start();
        return t;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestSwapPics();
            }
        });
    }

    private JButton jButton1;
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JPanel Panel;
    private int[] timings = {2000, 1000, 4000,5000,2000};
    private int count=0;

    }
```